# Sencha Touch MVC :: Trying to reach getValues() of Ext.extend(Ext.form.FormPanel,...)

Tags: model-view-controller, sencha-touch, extjs, formpanel

i am trying to reach the values of my form in my sencha touch application which i build out of a patchwork of tutorials. i want it to be a MVC pattern app so i use

```
app.views.Login = Ext.extend(Ext.form.FormPanel, formBase = {...})
```

and inside there initialising it with

```
 app.views.Login.superclass.initComponent.apply(this, arguments);
```

and a viewport like in the sencha touch phonegap MVC tutorial ([link](http://www.sencha.com/learn/Tutorial%3aA_Sencha_Touch_MVC_application_with_PhoneGap)) where I apply the login page like

```
Ext.apply(app.views, {loginPage: new app.views.Login()});
```

within my app when I click the send button of the form I try to catch the fields of the form

```
handler: function() {
    console.log('username ', app.views.Login.getValues().username);
    Ext.Ajax.request({
        url: app.views.Login.url,
        method: 'POST',
        params: {username: form.getValues().username, password : form.getValues().password},
        failure : function(response){
                    console.log('Login Error! ' + response.responseText);
                },
        success: function(response, opts) {
                    console.log('Login success! response: ' + response.responseText);
                  }
    });
}
```

but I allways get an error which says

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method
>   'getValues' of undefined"

when i use

```
console.log('username ', this.getValues().username);
```

so how could I reach the form values?

thnx!!!

Comment: I think you should also include the code of your send button (especially its `handler`) in the question.

Comment: edited: changed 'this.getValues().username' to 'app.views.Login.getValues().username' - but still not working. error: _"Uncaught TypeError: Object function (){ superclass.apply(this, arguments); } has no method 'getValues'"_

Comment: hm, so if there is no solution I think I have to put the login page out of the viewport...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at [Sencha Touch API Documentation](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/touch/docs/?class=Ext.form.FormPanel), I do not see a method `getForm()`, but `getValues()` should be reachable like this from your button `handler` function:

```
app.views.loginPage.getValues();
```

Comment: @Tommi hey thanx for your thgoughts on that. i have to appologize for my bad description. I edited my question, hoping to describe my problem better...

Comment: See my comment above - what does the `handler` look like?

Comment: but the form i define in the viewport with "Ext.apply(app.views, {loginPage: new app.views.Login()});" so where should I declare an additional "var login = new app.views.Login({...});"?

Comment: Ok. One more try. Updated my answer again.

Comment: samesame -> _Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'getValues'_

Comment: but with `console.log('app.views.loginPage', app.views.loginPage);` I get a subclass output - can't figure out if this helps...

Comment: in detail the subclass is:loginPage: `subclass
additionalCls: Array[0]
body: El.Ext.Element.Ext.extend.constructor
componentLayout: subclass
container: El.Ext.Element.Ext.extend.constructor
containsFormFields: true
dockedItems: Ext.util.MixedCollection
el: El.Ext.Element.Ext.extend.constructor
events: Object
fieldEventWrap: Object
fields: Ext.util.MixedCollection
getTargetEl: function () {
hiddenOwnerCt: false
id: "ext-comp-1005"
initialConfig: Object
items: Ext.util.MixedCollection
layout: subclass
...`

Comment: No probs, sorry I couldn't be of more help this time.

Comment: got it now! I put all form objects into own variables and the handler action into a controller. maybe that was the trick...